# JavaFX: SplitMenuButton: add elements from MySQL query

Tags: mysql, javafx

I have SplitMenuButton in my Controller called selectName with a default MenuItem as "none" value. I would like to make an SQL query and store the result inside the MenuButton. I made the Statement and the ResultSet, but I have no idea how to store the ResultSet data inside the MenuButton. Thinking about making a modell, with a name value but it isn't a TableView. Here is my code so far:

```
 private void setMenuButton() {
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM myTable");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            //add elements
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddNewProductController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a menu item from each element in the result set, and add it to the menu button:

```
private void setMenuButton() {
    try {
        pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT name FROM myTable");
        rs = pst.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next()) {
            String name = rs.getString("name");
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem(name);
            // add event handlers, etc, as needed..
            selectName.getItems().add(menuItem);
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(AddNewProductController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```